# Characterizing functions that are limits of integrable lower-bounded functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, integration, limits-and-convergence, measurable-functions

Let $X$ be a separable Hausdorff topological space, endowed with a positive finite Borel regular measure. Consider those (trivially measurable) functions $f : X \to \mathbb R$ such that their truncations $f_k = \max(f, -k)$ are integrable for all $k \in \mathbb N$.

> How can one recognize these functions, i.e. characterize them through properties equivalent to the one described above, but different from it (assuming that alternative characterizations are known)?

Comment: So, now I would say that the equivalent characterization is: $f$ satisfies what you wrote iff $f$ is measurable and $f^+$ is integrable, where $f^+=\max(f,0)$.

Comment: @LorenzoPompili: Indeed, this looks to be it, thank you.